# How to add options to drop down list and save it to the database?

Tags: php, jquery, database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I'm new to codeigniter and I'm really confused on how to add options to the drop down list and save the added options in the drop down list to the database. Can anyone help me with this?

My View:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>My Form</title>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myselect').change(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() == "addother") {

        $('#addother').show();

        $('#addother_input').val('');

    } else {
        $('#addother').hide();
    }
    });

      $('#add').click(function() {
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                     url: window.location,// use ci url here(i.e call controller)
                     data: { selectboxvalue: $options.val() } ///value will be sent
                      })
                    .done(function( msg ) {
                    $('#add').html(msg);
                     });
             });

});

  </script>
  <style>
     #addother {
     display: none;
     }

   </style>
 </head>


 <body>

 <div id="container">
    <?php 
       $options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
              'addother' => "Add other..."
            );

       echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, null, 'id="myselect"');

     ?>
      <div id="addother">
        <?php  echo form_input(array('id'=>'addother_input', 'name'=>'add', 'placeholder'=>'Enter name of school...')); ?>
        <input type="submit" id="add" name="submit" value="+" />
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
    function add() {
         $this->load->model('fruit_model');

         $data['selectboxvalue'] = $this->input->post('selectboxvalue');

         $res = $this->model->addItem($data);

         $this->load->view('myform');
     }

    function drop() {

         $this->load->model('getAll');

         $data["opt"] = $this->fruit_model->getAll();

         $this->load->view('myform');
     }
```

My Model:

```
     function getAll() {

       $query = $this->db->get('fruits')
       return $query->result();

      }

     function addItem($data){
         $this->db->insert('fruits', $data);
         return;
      }
```

How to save the added options into the database?

Comment: u mean u need to add values dynamically in select box and save it in database

Comment: yes sir. i'm really having trouble with it.

Comment: do one thing just use ajax to save and show dropdown from ajax response...

Comment: do you have an example for that sir?So that I could review it and understand what it does.

Comment: see my answer.if ur not satisfy i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

I giving simple php answer....change that to ci type

html & ajax code:

```
  <input type="text" name="selct" id="name" ><input type="submit" id="submit"/>
 <div id="box"> <select name="selectbox" id="testselect"></select></div>
  <script>
 $('#submit').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: "some.php",// use ci url here(i.e call controller)
           data: { selectboxvalue: $("#name").val() } ///value will be sent
            })
          .done(function( msg ) {
          $('#box').html(msg);
           });
   });
   </script>
```

Some.php page

```
   database connection

   insert $_post['selectboxvalue'] value in your database and fetch all values
   from database and populate in select box.i think it is easy so i am not writing 
   the code
```

Comment: I have just edited my codes in my post. Can you please help me solve it. What seems to be missing in my codes? Still can't add options into the drop down list.

Comment: in that code u need to take out the $ajax out of .change function...and value is not also catching in jquery.and your drop down is not fetching from database ...try to fetch drop down values from database

Comment: what does the selectboxvalue mean?is that a variable?

Comment: I already put the $ajax out of the .change function and I still cannot add an option into the dropdownlist.

Comment: are you populating dropdown from database

Comment: I cannot populate the dropdown from database because I cannot even add data from database. can you help how to add data into the database?

Answer (score -1):

try this example

```
<?php

class Options extends CI_Controller{

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('view name');

}

function create()
{
    $data = array(

        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'price' => $this->input->post('price'));

    $this->data_model->addItem($data);
    $this->index();
}

}

Model

<?php

class Data_model extends CI_Model {
function getAll() {
$q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM items");
if($q->num_rows() >0){
    foreach($q->result() as $row){
        $data[]=$row;
    }
}
return $data;
}

function addItem($data){
    $this->db->insert('items', $data);
    return;
}
}
?>

View

<html><head></head><body>
<style type="text/css">
label {display: block;}
</style>


<h2>Create</h2>
<?php echo form_open('controllername/function name/'); ?>

<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="name">Price</label>
    <select name="price">
      <option value="1">$100</option>
      <option value="2">$200</option>
      <option value="3">$300</option>
    </select>
</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! but what I want to do is to just add an option inside the drop down list and save it into the database.